# HowTo: OpenWRT routing/tunneling all traffic through an inline Snort sensor

Tags: networking, iptables, linux-networking, openwrt, network-traffic

I want all traffic that hits the OpenWRT router redirecting/tunneling through a dedicated Snort/Suricata machine before it leaves the local network. The Snort/Suricata machine should act as an inline passive (!) IDS, but does only have 1 eth0 device.

- OpenWRT Router Barrier Breaker (`192.168.1.1`) provides ethernet LAN, WiFi and OpenVPN.
- Clients (`192.168.1.x`)
- VPN Clients (`192.168.10.x`)
- Snort/Suricata machine (`192.168.1.200`)

1. What iptables do I have to use on the OpenWRT router to redirect/ tunnel all traffic through the IDS sensor?
2. What iptables do I have to use on the Snort/Suricata machine? As the traffic comes in at eth0, gets inspected, and then exits the machine at eth0 to the router and to its destination.

*I know that usually packet-mirroring is used, but I am only interested in the scenario as described.*

Answer (score 0):

Use VLANs. See: router on a stick, http://wikipedia.org/wiki/One-armed_router